# How can I get rid of border doubling while stacking two rectangles manually?

Tags: wpf, canvas, border

I have two rectangles on Canvas, one on top of the other.
The first is located at Y1, the second's height is H and its location is set to Y1 - H.
With this configuration I see double-sized border between them. SnapToDevicePixels is true for both rectangles.

How can I rid of this effect?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of e.g. the upper rectangle's lower border like this:

BorderThickness="1,1,1,0"

(or -vice-versa, the lower rectangle's upper border)

Comment: There's not BorderThickness in System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle class.

Comment: Ok, sorry - maybe you can use Border instead of Rectangle? (it's very similiar to a rectangle)